# Book about a boy who falls through a hole and ends up in an underground society

Tags: story-identification, books, underground-civilization

I read this book in ~2010-2015 and it was a series about a boy who's father went missing years ago. He was doing laundry one day and fell into an air vent of some sort and ended up in this underground society. I remember that cockroaches were the size of small dogs and very smart. Bats were also very smart and could be made friends with and ridden. He spends most the first book trying to return to his home.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*[Gregor the Overlander](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/262430.Gregor_the_Overlander)* by Suzanne Collins

[image: Front cover of Gregor the Overlander]

> When Gregor falls through a grate in the laundry room of his apartment building, he hurtles into the dark Underland, where spiders, rats, cockroaches coexist uneasily with humans. This world is on the brink of war, and Gregor's arrival is no accident. A prophecy foretells that Gregor has a role to play in the Underland's uncertain future. Gregor wants no part of it -- until he realizes it's the only way to solve the mystery of his father's disappearance. Reluctantly, Gregor embarks on a dangerous adventure that will change both him and the Underland forever.

Found with search terms of `novel boy "father * missing" "falls * vent"`

Comment: Using quote marks, and asterisks to indicate interim words, can do wonders for queries like this. :)

Comment: We'd have fewer questions if more people had stronger google-fu.

Comment: @DoscoJones very true, THis man googles on another level. I will use it to upgrade my google fu

Comment: @FuzzyBoots thanks for the quick answer and google fu advice. I will try to remember to use quotes and asterisks next time.